# Cannot install Nodejs 4 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, nodejs

I've run the following commands in my Vagrant machine. As you can see, I have Node 0.10.40 and I cannot make it update it to 4.4.3 which is the current LTS version.

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ node -v
v0.10.40
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ lsb_release -r
Release:        14.04
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo apt-get install --yes nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 178 not upgraded.
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ node -v
v0.10.40
```

These are the commands I used to install nodejs.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I also tried running `apt-get remove --purge nodejs` to no avail.

**Why does it not update?**

Comment: I added an answer suggesting to run `sudo apt-get update` but, looking the the script's source I see that it does it automatically. Removed my answer.

Comment: Yep I saw it and was going to say exactly that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to update it by compiling it from source:

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nodejs.org/dist/v4.4.3/node-v4.4.3.tar.gz
tar -xvzf node-v4.4.3.tar.gz
cd node-v4.4.3
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo npm install npm -g
```